# ThreadLocalRandom usage with thread pool application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So if spring boot uses a thread pool to handle incoming requests. there is no guarantee that **ThreadLocalRandom** outcome with not be the same because the seed (thread identity) may be the same in different consecutive requests. if this is correct what is the solution to overcome this

Comment: Spring doesn't use a threadpool tomcat does. Truly random still doesn't exists, that being said I don't really understand your question. The random will be reused based on the thread, but each call will have the next random (which depending on what you call can be the same).

Comment: Not sure what you're worrying about: is it (A) that two different requests could use a RandomGenerator with the same seed and therefore by chance producing the same random sequence? Or is it (B) how you can create the same random sequence for two different requests? Or is it (C) something else?